# How do I create an instance of an F# option type using Activator.CreateInstance?

Tags: .net, reflection, f#

I can create a function to create an option type based on any type:

```
let createOptionType typeParam =
    typeof<unit option>.GetGenericTypeDefinition().MakeGenericType([| typeParam |])
```

...and I can confirm that the function works:

```
createOptionType (typeof<int>) = (Some 5).GetType() // returns true
```

...and I can create the value "Some 0" by doing this:

```
System.Activator.CreateInstance(x.GetType(), [| null |]) // returns Some 0
```

However, I don't know how to create any other "Some x" value, or how to create "None". (It appears that it creates "Some ", because for strings it's "Some null".)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let makeOptionValue typey v isSome =
    let optionType = createOptionType typey
    let cases = FSharp.Reflection.FSharpType.GetUnionCases(optionType)
    let cases = cases |> Array.partition (fun x -> x.Name = "Some")
    let someCase = fst cases |> Array.exactlyOne
    let noneCase = snd cases |> Array.exactlyOne
    let relevantCase, args =
        match isSome with
        | true -> someCase, [| v |]
        | false -> noneCase, [| |]
    FSharp.Reflection.FSharpValue.MakeUnion(relevantCase, args)
```

Examples:

```
makeOptionValue typeof<int> 3 true          // returns "Some true"
makeOptionValue typeof<int> null false      // returns "None"
```